# Hit external IPs from microservices using Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I'm trying to hit external services from one of my microservices. I'm using Spring Cloud, Eureka for the registry and Spring boot as main framework.

```
Map<String, String> urlVariables = new HashMap<>();
    urlVariables.put("ip_address", IP);
    urlVariables.put("port", PORT);

    ResponseObject state =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://{ip_address}:{port}/state/", ResponseObject.class, urlVariables);
```

From what I see, Spring Cloud injects Ribbon as the HTTP client for the Rest Template, and when I try to hit this IP (e.g: `193.172.x.x`) it produces the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for 193.172.x.x
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:540)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:247)

It looks like Ribbon is trying to find a microservice instance with that name instead of looking outside. Is there any way to configure Ribbon to look for external IPs, or is it only for internal use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are injecting a @LoadBalanced version of RestTemplate. You have to ensure that your RestTemplate is a plain vanilla one. You can just create it with `new RestTemplate()`. If it's a bean just add a qualifier to ensure you're injecting a proper version of `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

On thing you could try is to use the service id in your code and configure the real instances:

```
ResponseObject state =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://myExternalService/state/", ResponseObject.class, urlVariables);
```

Than you configure a static list of endpoints for your service

```
myExternalService.ribbon.listOfServers=http://ip:port
```

This way you do not use service discovery for this service.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-ribbon-without-eureka

Comment: It does work but only if I disable eureka. Unfortunatelly I need eureka and also that service. Is there any way of making both work at the same time?

Comment: Yes, use `@LoadBalanced` for the one with ribbon like Marcin said, and label the non-eureka rest template as `@Primary`.